# LinkColour Legend in networkD3

Tags: r, shiny, networkd3

I'm plotting a `networkD3` graph with the `forceNetwork`

```
     forceNetwork(Links = links, 
                  Nodes = nodes,
                  Source = "source", 
                  Target = "target",
                  NodeID = "nodeID",
                  Group = "group",
                  linkColour = "colour",
                  Nodesize = "nodesize", 
                  zoom=TRUE,
                  legend = TRUE)
```

And i got this:

[image]

I'd like to add another `legend` with the `color of the links`.

I've searched but still couldn't find. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Documentation says "linkColour: character vector specifying the colour(s) you want the link lines to be. Multiple formats supported (e.g. hexadecimal).", so I'm not sure how you got that output.

Comment: A legend for the color of the links is not currently a supported feature. This has been asked before here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523838/showing-edge-legends-with-networkd3